# Store these arrays of prices and date in panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following arrays of prices and date.

```
price_1 = []
price_2 = []
date = []
```

I would like to fill these 3 arrays into a panda dataframe `df`. After storing into `df`, I want to be able to do something like retrieving the average of `price_1` using `df.price_1.mean()`.

I am using python v3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to have lists of equal lenght, but if you do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'price_1' : price_1,
                  'price_2': price2,
                  'date': date
                  })
```

Then you can use `df.price_1.mean()`

Comment: Lol the exact same answer as me, huh

Comment: yup, seems like miliseconds matter here :) I'll delete mine as it seems like you were first

Answer (score 2):

This ONLY works if the lists are of the same length.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'price_1':price_1,'price_2':price_2,'date':date})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length equal before creating pandas DataFrame:

```
if len(price_1) AND len(price_2) == len(date):
    return print("Length of lists are equal! You can create DataFrame")
else:
    return print("Your length are not equal! You can not create DataFrame")
```